# How do I prevent the VM in Microsoft Environment Viewer hijacking my "local" mouse during coded-ui automation test runs?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, hyper-v, microsoft-test-manager

I've successfully run CUIT automations for about a year without this problem. I use the Microsoft Environment Viewer bundled with Microsoft Test Manager and Visual Studio 2013 to connect to the machines in a SCVMM/Hyper-V lab environment. Then I kick off the automation, minimize the environment viewer, and work on something else while my tests run.

For thousands of test-runs, my "local" mouse has been unaffected by the automation script running on the virtual machine(s), but that changed recently after I set up a new lab environment containing 4 desktop client VMs. When I run tests on the new lab my pointer moves around my own screen--even after I've minimized the automation window.

Comment: I ended up deleting the 4-machine environment since it wasn't useable. Environments i created later (with one client VM each) did not manifest the mouse-grabbing bug. Before deleting the bad environment, i noticed that the mouse-jacking only occurred on my primary monitor. If i changed which monitor was my primary, the mouse bug moved to the new primary.

Comment: Just curious why you need to login to the environment first prior to kicking off the process - my guess is to get a better resolution on the agent prior to the test run?

Comment: @JL, the scenario I described above actually came from a technician on my team. I joined last year to help them get more out of their tools. They've been using the Lab Environment Viewer like a resizeable RDP window.